# jquery droppable get drag content

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

my codes: [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/uCasEKuZ/1/edit)

how can i copy draggable item HTML codes to droppable item?

i create this with JQUERY tutorial

HTML :

```
<div id="draggable1" class="ui-widget-content">
        <div class="dragcontent1class" id="dragcontent1id"><div>drag 1 some html codes</div></div>
</div>
<div id="draggable1" class="ui-widget-content">
    <div class="dragcontent2class" id="dragcontent2id"><div>drag 2 some html codes</div></div>
</div>
<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
    <div class="dropclass" id="dropid"><div>drop here</div></div>
</div>
```

and JQUERY:

```
<script>
    $(".ui-widget-content").draggable({ revert: true });
    $("#droppable").droppable({ accept: ".ui-widget-content",
        activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
        tolerance: "pointer"
    });

    $("#droppable").on("drop", function (event, ui) {
        $(this)
    .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
    .find("div")
    .html("Droped");
    });

</script>
```

in this codes after droped then "Droped" display in drob box

but how can i display draggable items sub codes

for example : if draggable1 item droped so dropb box sub codes show this codes:

```
<div class="dragcontent1class" id="dragcontent1id"><div>drag 1 some html codes</div></div>
```

sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically we make use of `clone()` to get the exact copy of the object.

I have made a demo for you, check if this is what u need

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ajey/j29d7/)

Comment: but demo not work 
after drop : drop box display Droped
not show dragged item html codes

Answer (score 0):

My draggable element is

```
$('.scp-el-draggable-row').draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: "move",
    opacity: 0.6,
    revert: "invalid"
});
```

Use following code if you need to add custom html

```
$('#main-body').droppable({
    accept: ".scp-el-draggable-row",
    activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
        .append( "<div class='row'></div>" );
    }
});
```

Or if you need to add html of dragged html, use this

```
$('#main-body').droppable({
    accept: ".scp-el-draggable-row",
    activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $( this )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
        .append( ui.draggable[0].outerHTML ); // this adds original draggable element
    }
});
```

following code adds cloned element

```
 $('#main-body').droppable({
    accept: ".scp-el-draggable-row",
    activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
        .append( ui.helper[0].outerHTML ); // this adds cloned draggable element
    }
});
```